# how convert code composable activity to empty activity?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

this project observation internet connectivity ,how i convert code from composablle activity to empty activity what instant of collectAsState for empty activity

get code form video youtube [observation internet connectivity video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzV0oCRDNfM)

interface observeconnectivity

```
package com.plcoding.observeconnectivity

import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

interface ConnectivityObserver {

fun observe(): Flow<Status>

enum class Status {
    Available, Unavailable, Losing, Lost
 }
}
```

observeconnectivity class

```
package com.plcoding.observeconnectivity

import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Network
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.awaitClose
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.callbackFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.distinctUntilChanged
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class NetworkConnectivityObserver(
private val context: Context
): ConnectivityObserver {

private val connectivityManager =
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

override fun observe(): Flow<ConnectivityObserver.Status> {
    return callbackFlow {
        val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                super.onAvailable(network)
                launch { send(ConnectivityObserver.Status.Available) }
            }

            override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
                super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive)
                launch { send(ConnectivityObserver.Status.Losing) }
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                super.onLost(network)
                launch { send(ConnectivityObserver.Status.Lost) }
            }

            override fun onUnavailable() {
                super.onUnavailable()
                launch { send(ConnectivityObserver.Status.Unavailable) }
            }
        }

        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback)
        awaitClose {
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback)
        }
    }.distinctUntilChanged()
}
```

}

how convert MainActivity  composble activity  to empty activity?

```
package com.plcoding.observeconnectivity

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.plcoding.observeconnectivity.ui.theme.ObserveConnectivityTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.launchIn
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onEach

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

private lateinit var connectivityObserver: ConnectivityObserver

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    connectivityObserver = NetworkConnectivityObserver(applicationContext)
    setContent {
        ObserveConnectivityTheme {
            val status by connectivityObserver.observe().collectAsState(
                initial = ConnectivityObserver.Status.Unavailable
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(text = "Network status: $status")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

theme.kt

```
package com.plcoding.observeconnectivity.ui.theme

import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.darkColors
import androidx.compose.material.lightColors
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
primary = Purple200,
primaryVariant = Purple700,
secondary = Teal200
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
primary = Purple500,
primaryVariant = Purple700,
secondary = Teal200

/* Other default colors to override
background = Color.White,
surface = Color.White,
onPrimary = Color.White,
onSecondary = Color.Black,
onBackground = Color.Black,
onSurface = Color.Black,
*/
 )

 @Composable
 fun ObserveConnectivityTheme(
darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
val colors = if (darkTheme) {
    DarkColorPalette
} else {
    LightColorPalette
}

MaterialTheme(
    colors = colors,
    typography = Typography,
    shapes = Shapes,
    content = content
)
```

}